# if mysql columns =x echo 'x' else if y echo 'y'

Tags: php, mysql

i have a script which i am using to check the status of applications in my database, everytime a user submits an application there are 4 columns in the database, 'form1_completed', 'form2_completed', 'form3_completed' and 'form4_completed' each of these will get updated from 'no' to 'yes' depending on which application they submit.

the mysql query basically searches for any rows in the database which are set to 'no', i.e. form1_completed ='no' or form2_completed = 'no' and if anyone of these is set to 'no' it says the status of the application process is pending

likewise if a user has submitted all the applications, then all 4 columnns will be updated to 'yes' and the second part of my query tells us that the application process is complete.

now i have introduced another element in my code, where if a user submits an application and they have filled it in incorrectly or they haven't passed the initial checks then a column in the database called 'status' will update to 'Failed'.

so what i want to do is if the 'status' column has a value of 'failed' in it then i want the application process to be listed as 'failed' rather than pending, but because one or more of the 4 columns; 'form1_completed', 'form2_completed' etc will still have no in them then mysql is echoing this out as application pending still. But what i want to do is say some how that if 'status' is set to failed then say application process failed otherwise if 'status' is empty or 'failed' doesnt exist then application process will be pending

please can someone show me how i need to amend my script to make this work

```
 <?php include 'config.php';
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, CURDATE()) AS expire_date
                     FROM supplier_session 
                     WHERE form1_completed = 'No' 
                       OR form2_completed = 'No' 
                       OR form3_completed = 'No' 
                       OR form4_completed = 'No'
                     ORDER BY expire_date ASC") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 

     echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:995px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:11px;\" >

<tr>
    <td style=\"width:100px;\">ID:</td><td>Company Name:</td><td>Company Reg No:</td><td>Application Started:</td><td style=\"width:200px;\">Application Duration:</td><td>Status:</td></tr>";


     while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
       $days = $row['expire_date'];
       $when = $days*0; 
       $str = $row['expire_date'];
       $str2 = substr($str, 0); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."


       if ($when <= 31){
         echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
         echo "<td>"; echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['date'])); echo "</td>";

         if ($days >= 8) {
             echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>";
             print ($str2 -7);
            echo " days overdue</td>";      
         }


        elseif ($when <= 7){
             echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>{$str2} of 7 days past</td>";
          }

        }

        $q2 = "SELECT * FROM supplier_session 
               WHERE form1_completed = 'NO' 
                 OR form2_completed = 'NO' 
                 OR form3_completed = 'NO' 
                 OR form4_completed = 'NO'" 
              or die (mysql_error());
    $result2 = mysql_query($q2);
    $count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

    echo "<td>";
    echo "Pending</td>";
    echo "<tr>";

     }


 $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,
                              TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, CURDATE()) AS expire_date
                      FROM supplier_session 
                      WHERE form1_completed = 'Yes' 
                        AND form2_completed = 'Yes' 
                        AND form3_completed = 'Yes' 
                        AND form4_completed = 'Yes'
                      ORDER BY expire_date ASC") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 


     while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) { 
       $days = $row['expire_date'];
       $when = $days*0; 
       $str = $row['expire_date'];
       $str2 = substr($str, 0); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."


       if ($when <= 31){
         echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
         echo "<td style=\"width:203px;\">"; echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['date'])); echo "</td>";


        echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p> Completed in ";
             print ($str2);
            echo " days</td>";      
         }

        $q2 = "SELECT * FROM supplier_session 
               form1_completed = 'Yes' AND form2_completed = 'Yes' AND form3_completed = 'Yes' AND form4_completed = 'Yes'" 
             or die (mysql_error());
    $result2 = mysql_query($q2);
    $count2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

    echo "<td>";
    echo "Completed</td>";
    echo "<tr>";

     }

      echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML


  ?>
```

Comment: where did you got stuck? just update the application status to failed when the form submission failed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the various queries to include the test for any of the form* columns being failed or not.

Here is the 'pending' query:

```
SELECT * FROM supplier_session 
               WHERE 
                 (    form1_completed = 'NO' 
                  OR form2_completed = 'NO' 
                  OR form3_completed = 'NO' 
                  OR form4_completed = 'NO')
               AND NOT ('failed' IN (form1_completed,
                                     form2_completed,
                                     form3_completed,
                                     form4_completed ))
```